# Get executable path of a jar in java 7

Tags: java-7, executable-jar

Before everybody tells me this is a duplicate, please hear me out...

When you need the absolute executable path from inside a running jar (= path to self) regardless of the current working directory, in the old days (Java 6 JRE 1.6) this used to work like a charm:

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Nowadays in Java 7 (JRE 1.7) this just returns "./". If you want to test this, you'll need to create a runnable jar because when compiling from the source, you will get the path as expected.

This is driving me mad as I have been searching for a solution for what seems like an eternity. I resorted to hardcoding the absolute path, but obviously that means the jar is not portable.

Does anyone know what to do?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across the same problem after exporting one of my older Java 6 projects which also used the same method to get the execution path.
Here's a quick workaround (replace 'Start.class' with your class name or use 'getClass()'):

```
String path = Start.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
path = new File(rootFolder).getAbsolutePath();
```

Most likely you will end up with a path still ending with a period. So you might want to fix that using:

```
if (path.endsWith(".")) path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
```

Tested using Oracle JRE 7 on Windows 7 64bit and Xubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sorry haven't had a chance to try. Will get back on this asap